# How to prove $f\left( x\right) =\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac {1}{2^{n}}\cos\left( 3^{n}x\right)$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I understood what uniform convergence means, but I cannot even find clue how I get into proof.

Comment: Then, you **didn't** understand what uniform convergence means.

Comment: @ProfessorVector okay, I admit to this sir. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weierstrass M-Test to $\left|\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\cos(3^{n}x)\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}<\infty$.

Comment: ouu, I forgot the M-test... Thanks mate. :)